# Discord.js - Check if user is muted / mute change

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a bot that server-mutes everyone if a specific person mutes themself.

I can get the user ID or other details via `message.member`.
Is there any way to find out if that user is muted or even if the person is in a voice channel?

This is what I found so far:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldmember, newmember) => {
   let oldvoice = oldmember.voiceChannel;
   let newvoice = newmember.voiceChannel;
   if (oldvoice && newvoice && oldvoice.id != newvoice.id) 
      var channelStatus = 'Moved'

   console.log(oldvoice)
})
```

But I don't understand it and it just returns undefined.

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: How do I know? I guess that I'm using the latest one.

Comment: If you are using `V12`, Try this: `oldmember.voice.channel` and `newmember.voice.channel`

Comment: just checked, I am using V12.3.1, but doesn't matter, because I found a way myself.
I am going to post it in a second.

Comment: it gives me an error saying cannot read property channel of undefined...

Comment: That's odd, since `voiceChannel` is deprecated and removed in V12. `VoiceStateUpdate` should return the [VoiceState class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) instead. Can you only log `oldvoice` in the console? Does it return anything?

Comment: I am using node in cmd how do I run commands in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Found a way easier solution:

```
msg.member.voice.selfMute
```

Old one:

```
client.channels.cache.get(msg.member.voice.channel.id).guild.voiceStates.cache.get(msg.author.id).selfMute
```

let's break it down:
**client.channels.cache** gives you of all text and voice channels in your discord server
**get(msg.member.voice.channel.id)** gives you the id of the voice channel, the user that wrote the bot command (considering, you have stored the message in a variable e.g.: msg)
**.guild.voiceStates.cache** gives you a list of everyone in the channel
**.get(msg.author.id)** takes the user that wrote the last message
**.selfMute** returns the mute state

btw there are other pretty useful things too like selfDeafen, streaming and more